# Problem running react native simulator ios

Tags: xcode, react-native, macos-mojave

i have a problem when i run `npx react-native run-ios`

the problem is

```
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures 
and Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. 
(in target 'React-cxxreact' from project 'Pods')

warning: None of the architectures in ARCHS (x86_64) are valid. 
Consider setting ARCHS to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) 
or updating it to include at least one value from VALID_ARCHS (i386, x86_64) which is not in EXCLUDED_ARCHS (x86_64). 
(in target 'React-cxxreact' from project 'Pods')
```

i am using

`"react-native": "0.65.1"`

`"react": "17.0.2"`

`Osx Mojave, with Excode 11`

how to solved the problem, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in react native cli and  my xcode , when I create new project with expo and do inject the problem solved